# How can we use AWS services to create a complete chat module in our iOS app with Video, Audio and Text chat capabilities?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, amazon-web-services, videochat

I need to develop an iOS health care application with **HIPAA compliance**. Since the HIPAA compliance doesn't allow the use of any third party Chat SDKs, I need to implement the entire chat module including video conference using AWS services.

I have read about *AWS CloudFront* for media streaming. Can anyone suggest a better approach for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can go for a serverless real-time chat application with AWS. You can create separate Lambda Functions as microservices for textual and video conferencing. Then configure these lambda functions to be triggered by CloudFront Events. You can also check which type of events are being triggered in CloudFront and perform the desired function.

Answer (score 2):

First of all you need a [AWS Certified Solutions Architect - Associate](https://aws.amazon.com/certification/certified-solutions-architect-associate/)   and his responsibilities is

- Maintain AWS account for you.
- Manages all the resources(EC2, cloudfront, S3, DynamoDB.. etc) for you.
- Now you have to store all the chats by using DynamoDB.
- Use S3 to store files (images, video, others).
- [Cloudfront](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/Introduction.html) is used to provide the files on user end w/o any latency .

You simply can assume he is person how manages the sever like in simple API calls some other PHP developer gives you all APIs and manages DB.

**Doc Reference :** https://aws.amazon.com/documentation/sdk-for-ios/

Now your responsibility is to use above mentioned api calls and create the app. For UI design you can use any third party or can customise yourself.

> Edit:

Or you can use serverless concept as stated in other answer.